# Proper way of doing a Twitter-like follower and retweets system on CakePHP 2?

Tags: php, cakephp, twitter, has-and-belongs-to-many

I'm super new to CakePHP. I've searched everywhere for this but I can't seem to be able to get it right, or find any sort of orientation. I still don't get how the whole HABTM thing works and I'm expecting to learn more from this.

I'm trying to do a Twitter-like system, with users and followers, and posts (tweets) and shares (retweets). I've set up the users and posts models, and join tables for followers (between users and users) and shares (between users and posts). How should I set up my model associations? I've been trying several ways but I'm not certain on whether I'm doing it right or not.

And the other question is, what would be the proper find query to get all posts by the people I follow, plus the posts they've shared, without getting all the unnecessary data like user info and such, just the posts in one array? Is it possible with find in one query, or should I do several and then merge the arrays? Plus, it would be extremely useful to understand how to properly filter and limit this rather complex query (obtaining a "posts timeline" between certain date ranges, limit the posts to a certain amount, or both).

I know my question is a little bit silly, but I swear I've done a lot of research and I can't seem to be able to get it right. So any help, especially with the query part, would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

So these would be some weird relationships. I'm feeling you should have the following tables:

- Users (with alias Followers) hasMany tweets
- Posts belongsTo Users
- UsersFollowers (A HABTM table)

To make this work on just three tables, `Posts` would need to be a threaded table. In essence, if a person retweets (shares) a post a new record is created with the id of the original post in the new posts `parent_id` column. Then when the record was called the model could pull up the additional data and include it in the feed.

The alias aspect of `Users` allows for the follower part to be done in just one table. To find followers of a person, search with one key of the table (`follower_id`) and to find the people a person follows just search with the other key (`users_id`).

As for the second part of your question, finds should be pretty easy in this setup, but you might want to read up on [Containable](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/behaviors/containable.html) and [threaded queries](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html#find-threaded). You could include timestamp columns in the tables so you could later do a search by date feature (or a post timeline).